# Is GWT really compiling the client code to JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: gwt

I have a serious doubt on using GWT. GWT claims that the client codes are compiled to JavaScript and HTML, but after compiling the code, I'm still seeing .class files for the client code in my Project. Of course i do have some js and html files in WEB-INF directory, but if the java client code is completely compiled to js and html, why would there be .class files in the project?

Comment: If your application makes RPC calls to the server your *`server`* code is still compiled Java class files. Only client side code is compiled into javascript.

Comment: The .class files are due to silly Eclipse senselessly compiling away any java files it could lay its eyes on.

Unless they are server-side of RPC or RequestFactory classes, they are useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very straightforward, if you know what is GWT. According to the Wikipedia:

GWT applications can be run in two modes:

> - **Development mode (formerly Hosted mode):** The application is run as    Java bytecode within the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). This mode
>     is    typically used for development, supporting hot swapping of code
>     and    debugging.
> - **Production mode (formerly Web mode):** The application is run as pure    JavaScript and HTML, compiled from the Java source. This mode
>     is    typically used for deployment.

I think you understand why you are seeing Java bytecode files(.class) are in your project. For checking it: start your project and open the web page which is generated by gwt, delete .class file(s) from client package, and it won't work. But in production mode it works properly since it doesn't depend on some .class files. For example, the classes which are responsible for constructing the UI.

Comment: The only exception would be server classes, or classes help in common to both (and so needed by the server). In both cases, the server JVM actually loads the classes, so they must be compiled.

Comment: @ColinAlworth By saying it doesn't depend on some .class, I mean classes which are responsible for constructing the UI for example `MyModuleEntryPoint`, so without such classes your compiled js and html can work.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to clarify that deleting all .class files in the client package could cause some breakage.

Comment: IDEs like eclipse will also create the class files in the build folder in order to validate your code.  Also, compiled versions of a generator needs to be in the classpath of the GWT compiler. Rather than requiring my ant scripts to designate which packages contain generators I just javac my entire project temporarily into the classpath of the GWT compiler(considering that a GWT compile takes 100x longer than a javac the time increase is negligible)

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to GAE , you would see a directory "WAR". This WAR is what is deployed to server and has pure JS+HTML code for client side code.